# Data not sending to Access database using VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am having trouble with the following code; it is not sending to the database

I have included all code in case there is a problem elsewhere that is effecting the sending of data to the database

The code is not throwing any errors when running or when `btnBook` is clicked

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmBookRoom
    Private DB As New DBControl
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;")

    Private Function NotEmpty(text As String) As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)
    End Function

    Private Sub AddBooking()
        'Add parameters
        DB.AddParam("@RoomType", cbxRoomType.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@CheckIn", txtCheckIn.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@Checkout", txtCheckOut.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@NoNights", txtNights.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@Adults", txtAdults.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@Children", txtChildren.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@FullName", txtName.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@Revenue", txtPrice.Text)
        DB.AddParam("@DateBooked", Date.Today)

        'Execute insert command
        DB.ExecQuery("INSERT INTO tblRoomBookings([RoomType], [CheckIn], [Checkout], [NoNights], [Adults], [Children], [FullName], [Revenue], [DateBooked])" &
                         "VALUES(@RoomType, @CheckIn, @Checkout, @NoNiights, @Adults, @Children, @FullName, @Revenue, @DateBooked)")

        'Report and abort on errors
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DB.Exception) Then MsgBox(DB.Exception) : Exit Sub
        DBCon.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnBook_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBook.Click
        'Perform the sub routine AddBooking
        AddBooking()

        'Clear all the text boxes ready for the next entry
        cbxRoomType.Text = Nothing
        txtCheckIn.Clear()
        txtCheckOut.Clear()
        txtNights.Clear()
        txtAdults.Text = "2"
        txtChildren.Text = "0"
        txtName.Clear()
        txtPrice.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmBookRoom_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Open connection to the database
        If DBCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then DBCon.Open() : Exit Sub
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmBookRoom_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        'Calendar only displays dates from today forward
        MonthCalendar1.MinDate = Date.Today
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLessAdults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLessAdults.Click
        'Take one away from the number of adults
        txtAdults.Text -= 1
        'Don't allow the number to be less than one
        If txtAdults.Text <= 1 Then txtAdults.Text = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMoreAdults_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoreAdults.Click
        'Add one to the number of adults
        txtAdults.Text += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLessChildren_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLessChildren.Click
        'Take one away from the number of children
        txtChildren.Text -= 1
        'Don't allow the number of children to be less than zero
        If txtChildren.Text <= 0 Then txtChildren.Text = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMoreChildren_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMoreChildren.Click
        'Add one to the number of children
        txtChildren.Text += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrice_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrice.Click
        Dim Nights As Integer
        Nights = txtNights.Text
        'Calculation to work out the total price of the stay
        If cbxRoomType.Text = "single" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£99.99"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(99.99 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If

        If cbxRoomType.Text = "twin" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£124.99"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(124.99 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If

        If cbxRoomType.Text = "double" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£149.99"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(149.99 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If

        If cbxRoomType.Text = "double double" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£164.99"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(164.99 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If

        If cbxRoomType.Text = "mini suite" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£250"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(250 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If

        If cbxRoomType.Text = "master suite" Then
            If CDbl("0" + txtNights.Text = 1) Then
                txtPrice.Text = "£275"
            Else
                txtPrice.Text = "£" & Format(275 * (1.2 ^ Nights), "0.00")
            End If
        End If


        btnBook.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected
        'Automatically have the first and last date put into the corresponding textboxes
        txtCheckIn.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        txtCheckOut.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange.End.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    End Sub

    Private Sub cbxRoomType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxRoomType.SelectedIndexChanged, txtCheckIn.TextChanged, txtCheckOut.TextChanged, txtNights.TextChanged, txtName.TextChanged
        'Enable buttons for booking and seeingg the price when the length of stay is entered
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text) Then
            btnPrice.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        'Clear the form
        cbxRoomType.Text = Nothing
        txtCheckIn.Clear()
        txtCheckOut.Clear()
        txtNights.Clear()
        txtAdults.Text = "2"
        txtChildren.Text = "0"
        txtName.Clear()
        txtPrice.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtName_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtName.KeyPress
        'Only allow entry of letters
        If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) = True Then
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) = True Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnViewEditBookings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnViewEditBookings.Click
        'Display View and Edit Bookings form
        frmViewEditBookings.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtNights_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtNights.KeyPress
        'Only allow entry of numbers
        If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = True Then
            e.Handled = True
        ElseIf Char.IsPunctuation(e.KeyChar) = True Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        'Close the form
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: OleDb doesn't support named parameters. `@NoNiights` should be `@NoNights` - it has an extra `i`. Don't use a class-level `OleDbConnection`. Instead use [Using Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) in a method. See [System.Data.OleDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8) and [OleDbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that exceptions aren't being thrown but being swallowed somewhere where in the call stack  Perhaps update your question with the details of DBControl, specifically the ExecQuery method

Comment: I recommend to enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)